# How do you access to a Gmail inbox and manage emails using Python?

Tags: php, python, email, gmail

I've made a program to send mails, which have a numbers code in the subject. Now I need to write another one to be able to read through all the mail subjects searching for one specific one, and return the contents of the mail I was searching for.

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.voidynullness.net/blog/2013/07/25/gmail-email-with-python-via-imap/? (First hit with google.)

Answer (score 0):

To access your gmail inbox and manage emails you will have to use a module called "imaplib"
Here you have a short example to access your inbox:

```
import imaplib

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('youremail@gmail.com', 'yourpassword')
mail.list()
# Out: list of "folders" aka labels in gmail.
mail.select("inbox") # connect to inbox.
```

I'm sure you can continue from here.